# Use or access animation of imported model?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I downloaded a free package (with some turret models) from the asset store but don't know how to use its pre-built animation. The models have separate parts. I think I can animate the parts I want by creating the animations myself but looks like those models already have some pre-built animation. I can play it via the Inspector of the import settings (select the Animation tab), something like in this image:

[image]

However when I select the gameObject (created by dragging the model onto the scene) and open both the Animation and Animator window, I see nothing.

I only know how to play the animation in code if the object has some Animation or Animator components. This thing is very strange to me maybe because I'm still fairly new to Unity. Could you point me in the right direction on how to use that model with its designed animation in my code (means controlling it in code)? In other words, my problem can be solved if the integrated animation (built with the model) can be extracted and accessed like any other normal Animation Clips I can create.

Thanks for your time helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Hopeless what you're seeing is the old Animation procedure, it does not have Animator. So you have to do it the old way.

Way before, it is called Animation, but changed to (LEGACY) animation, which again, doesn't have animator.

To check this, you would have to go to Rig and see if it is on Legacy mode. If not, you would have to put it in Legacy mode because it is configured to Legacy.

To further understand how to use Legacy component.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Animations.html

To understand how to script with Legacy component.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationScripting.html

If you're not good in using Documents. At lease you already know what to Search for.

Legacy Unity3D animation <-- this one, you will get a lot of results. Good luck.

Comment: I checked out the Rig tab, the `Animation Type` shows `Generic`. Not sure what is old or new here but I successfully found the imported `Animation Clip`. It's very hidden under the model hierarchy. The model in the Project window appears like a Sprite bundle having an expanding arrow, clicking on that arrow shows all the sub parts of the model including the imported `Animation Clip`. So I now can use it. However your answer tells about Legacy and some kind of newer animation. I'm not sure how it matters here. I've read about Animations in the doc but nothing noticeable.

Comment: Generic type is used when you're using different kind of anim. For example animation that is generated by 3d modeling like 3ds max. Default name is a "take" then it is composed with different animation inside 1 take. Then it is cut down to pieces and renaming each peace as its own animation.  You can also alter the take in unity3d to cut your pieces of animation inside that take file.